# What must an EAR flle (java) contain?

Tags: ear

I am exploring Java EE 6 deployment choices. I understand what a WAR file is and, conceptually, I understand the purpose of an EAR file is to package together WAR modules and/or other Jar resources so that the whole deployment can be seamless.

My question is, what is the minimum that an EAR must contain. My investigation leads me to believe that there must be at least one WAR module present, as the EAR is nothing more than a wrapper and additional configuration xml.

Also, is there a definitive paper showing all the config files and the xml elements which could be included? (sometimes I find it easier to grasp concepts when I dive straight in and review the config options.)

Many thanks for your assistance